# Best Java Data Structure for Fast, Concurrent Insertions

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, data-structures, concurrency

My use case is as follows: I have 10 threads simultaneously writing to one data structure. The order of the elements in the data structure does not matter. All the elements are unique. I will only be doing a read from this data structure only once at the very end.

What would be the fastest native Java data structure to suit this purpose? From my reading, it seems `Collections.synchronizedList` might be the go to option?

Comment: filling means you just need fast write or fast read as well?

Comment: Fast write only. I will only be doing one read at the very end.

Comment: `Collections.synchronizedList` will work, but you still need to choose the backing list (e.g. `ArrayList`, `LinkedList`, etc.). Since elements are unique you could also try sets such as`ConcurrentSkipListSet` which will enforce uniqueness (perhaps that's useful to you?). Performance all depends on your read/write patterns. The best way to know will probably be to test it yourself.

Comment: Another possibility: avoid the synchronization entirely, write to 10 separate collections (one per thread), and only merge them at the end for the single read.

Comment: Is that you are just initialising your datastructure in the begining only or on an adhoc basis?

Comment: Do threads need to "see" values written by other threads?

Comment: @DavidSoroko No, they don't.

Comment: @SMA At the very beginning.

Comment: If each thread is writing into its own "slot", synchronizing on every access is excessive. It all down to visibility so you should be able to handle this with some volatile boundary

Comment: *10 threads simultaneously writing to one data structure.* the number of threads is not the only thing that matters. contention does, i.e. is it common for multiple threads to try to write *at the same time*. In other words, does writing to that data structure make up a large time-fraction spent by those 10 threads? If they do a lot of work and only write to it every now and then the choice of structure won't really matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have 10 threads simultaneously writing to one data structure.

I think it would be best to use a separate data structure per thread. That way no synchronisation is needed between the threads, and it would be much more CPU cache friendly too.

At the end they could be joined.

As for the underlying structure: if the elements are fixed size, an array/verctor would be best. Joining them would only take *a copy of the block of memory* they occupy, depending on the implementation - but lists would always be slower.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need for you to synchronize on a list as each of the thread can work on their local copy and at the end can join results from all the threads into one final list.

If am going to use JDK7 and above then I would use fork and join for the same where i would create simple `List` in each forked task and finally join it in the main list at the end in the join phase.

If am on JDK6 then i could use a `CountDownLatch` with count as 10. Each and every thread after writing to their individual list (passed to the thread from main controller thread) counts down the latch and in the main controller, once all threads are done, i would combine all the result into one.